# How to get the output of grep in C

Tags: c, grep

I'm executing grep command in my C code with the function execl(), and I want to use the output of this command in my C program. How do I do it?

Comment: @myaut Not a duplicate, since C is not C++.

Comment: @Jens: the difference is small, what OP needs is `popen()` (and that it is first answer there).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `popen`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *mode);
int pclose(FILE *stream);

int main(void)
{
    FILE *cmd;
    char result[1024];

    cmd = popen("grep bar /usr/share/dict/words", "r");
    if (cmd == NULL) {
        perror("popen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (fgets(result, sizeof(result), cmd)) {
        printf("%s", result);
    }
    pclose(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using `execl`, you can use a [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe).

There is some examples and tutorials [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html).